# Stats homework mean and standard deviation

Tags: statistics

For the following situation, find the mean and standard deviation of the population. List all the samples (with replacement) of the given size from that population. Find the mean and standard deviation of the sampling distribution and compare them with the mean and standard deviation of the population.

The number of DVDs rented by each of three families in the past month is 5,6, and $7$. Use a sample size of $2$.

I have the mean which is $6$ but I get lost after that.

Comment: how did you get the mean? what does standard deviation mean to you?

Comment: i added 5+6+7 then divided it by 3 and got 6.

Comment: for the standard deviation i have tried so many different things and even looked at the book and did the equation it had in the book and i get a different answer. I even looked at the help link it has online and followed that and still got the wrong number

Comment: do you know what the variance is?

Comment: i got the mean which is 6, and the standard deviation is .82.

Comment: 6 is the mean for the second part i just need help with the standard deviation of the sampling distribution

Comment: would it be .61?

Comment: can you edit your question to show how you got the answers you got?